# Como mostrar número de páginas na paginação handlebars?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js

Esse é meu código para calcular o número de páginas, aqui está calculando tudo corretamente, já testei.

```
app.get("/page/:page", (req, res) => {
    var perPage = 3
        , page = Math.max(0, req.params.page)

    Postagem.find().populate("categoria")
        .limit(perPage)
        .skip(perPage * (page - 1))
        .sort({
            data: "desc"
        })
        .exec(function (err, postagens) {
            Postagem.count().exec(function (err, count) {
                res.render('index', {
                    postagens: postagens,
                    page: page,
                    pages: count / perPage
                })
            })
        })
})
```

Abaixo meu handlebars, to tentando passar o número de pages calculadas pra criar mas não aparece nada:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-danger" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        {{#each pages}}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-danger" href="/{{page}}">{{pages}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-danger" href="/#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Mas não aparece nada, já tentei pesquisar no como fazer isso mas não encontrei em nenhum lugar...Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode dar uma olhada numa biblioteca chamada "Handlerbars Paginate helper". Para instalar, você faz o seguinte:

```
npm install handlebars-paginate
```

Você registra esta biblioteca como um helper

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var paginate = require('handlebars-paginate');

Handlebars.registerHelper('paginate', paginate);
```

E depois passa para o seu template um objeto com os dados da paginação

```
 pagination: {
    page: 4,       // Pagina atual
    pageCount: 10  // Total paginas
  }
```

Dentro do template, o layout ficaria assim:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
  <ul>
    {{#paginate pagination type="first"}}
      <li {{#if disabled}}class="disabled"{{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">First</a></li>
    {{/paginate}}
    {{#paginate pagination type="previous"}}
      <li {{#if disabled}}class="disabled"{{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Prev</a></li>
    {{/paginate}}
    {{#paginate pagination type="middle" limit="7"}}
      <li {{#if active}}class="active"{{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">{{n}}</a></li>
    {{/paginate}}
    {{#paginate pagination type="next"}}
      <li {{#if disabled}}class="disabled"{{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Next</a></li>
    {{/paginate}}
    {{#paginate pagination type="last"}}
      <li {{#if disabled}}class="disabled"{{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Last</a></li>
    {{/paginate}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Mais informações:

https://github.com/olalonde/handlebars-paginate
http://syskall.com/pagination-with-handlebars/